# how to Query parent to child

Tags: apex, soql, soql-injection

I have process in salesforce in such a way opportunity we can relate this opportunity to this lookup field parent_opportunity__c .
Which relates opportunity to other parent opportunity.

I want to write a query **parent to child** :

```
select id,(select id from opportunity where parent_opportunity__c!=null) from opportunity where parent_opportunity__c=null
```

I have worked with different scenarios i cant able to crack it

select id,name,(select id,name from parent_opportunity__r) from opportunity this is showing error and

select id,name,(select id,name from opportunity) from parent_opportunity__c this is also error

Comment: can you please check what is the relationship name used on the parent_opportunity__c field and try using that? for example: select id,name,(select id,name from relationshipNameOnTheLookupField) from opportunity

Comment: relationship name is    Opportunities

Comment: still i am getting th error

Comment: select id,name,(select id,name from opportunities) from opportunity
                                    ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:37
Didn't understand relationship 'opportunities' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the PLURAL of the `parent_opportunity` object name.

Given that your object is called `parent_opportunity__c`, it's likely your relationship is called something like `child_opportunities__r`. You can check this on the lookup field that defines this relationship.

Once you have that, use this field in your query - it should work.

You can see in the image of the definition of a lookup that the relationship from parent to child is `Screenings__r` and from child back up to `Opportunity` is Opportunity (as there is only one)

[image]